# Calculate slopes for samples with multiple replicates and categories

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have an experimental dataset that is rather complicated, so I created a simplified sample to help communicate the problem. The full experiment is a time course with 8 time points, 4 replicates, 4 categories (simplified to "gender" in the sample), and expression data from 26,000 genes. I figured if someone can help with the simpler dataset to address my problems it should apply to the larger dataset.

The simpler dataset (below) has 4 time points, 3 replicates, 2 genes, and measured expression (numeric non-negative values, there are decimals in the full dataset). I was able to copy and paste the following code directly into R and it worked.

```
sample <- structure(list(time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L), 
replicate = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), gene = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("gene1", "gene2"), class = "factor"), 
expression = c(1000L, 2000L, 1010L, 2010L, 1020L, 2020L, 
900L, 1900L, 910L, 1910L, 920L, 1920L, 700L, 1700L, 710L, 
1720L, 720L, 1750L, 500L, 1020L, 520L, 1010L, 510L, 1050L, 
1100L, 2100L, 1110L, 2110L, 1120L, 2120L, 1000L, 2000L, 1010L, 
2010L, 1020L, 2020L, 800L, 1800L, 810L, 1820L, 820L, 1850L, 
600L, 1120L, 620L, 1110L, 610L, 1150L)), .Names = c("time", 
"replicate", "gender", "gene", "expression"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
sample$replicate <- as.factor(sample$replicate)
```

Should look like this:

```
> head(sample)
  time replicate gender  gene expression
1    0         1   male gene1       1000
2    0         1 female gene1       2000
3    0         2   male gene1       1010
4    0         2 female gene1       2010
5    0         3   male gene1       1020
6    0         3 female gene1       2020
```

### My question is:

I want a list of slopes calculated using the replicates for each gene in each gender over the time course. I'm not sure if I expect the slopes to be linear or nonlinear, so it would be helpful to have the option of either. I expect the slopes to mostly be trending downward, but some may be positive as well.

I'm not averse to reshaping the data in a different way! I just don't know what format to put it in to achieve my goal. I have played around with both `reshape` and `reshape2` packages. At one point I had the data with "time" as a column, and 26,000 columns with expression values, but that was only **one** replicate for **one** category. Ultimately I have 4 replicates and 4 categories with 26,000 unique genes, so that's how I landed on this particular format/structure.

I need the slopes to perform some normalization calculations before using the data in a mixed effects model to find interactions between time and gender (or "category" in my big dataset), with replicate as a random effect.

Here is my `sessionInfo()` if it helps. Using `RStudio version 0.98.994`.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lme4_1.1-7           Rcpp_0.11.3          Matrix_1.1-4         gplots_2.14.2            RColorBrewer_1.0-5  
[6] ggplot2_1.0.0        reshape_0.8.5        BiocInstaller_1.16.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6       caTools_1.17.1     colorspace_1.2-4   digest_0.6.4       gdata_2.13.3          grid_3.1.2        
 [7] gtable_0.1.2       gtools_3.4.1       KernSmooth_2.23-13 lattice_0.20-29    MASS_7.3-35        minqa_1.2.4       
[13] munsell_0.4.2      nlme_3.1-118       nloptr_1.0.4       plyr_1.8.1         proto_0.3-10       reshape2_1.4      
[19] scales_0.2.4       splines_3.1.2      stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.1.2
```

Thanks so much for your help! Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: I suggest you show us how you create the model for an individual gene and we can take it from there. Are you looking for a mixed model to account for the possible correlation?

Comment: I really just want to get the slopes for now to do some normalization before I put the values into a mixed effects model (time ~ genotype as fixed effects, with replicate as random effect). Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this method using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>% 
    group_by(gene, gender) %>% 
    do(slope=lm(expression~time, .)$coef[2]) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

This will return

```
   gene gender     slope
1 gene1 female -20.91111
2 gene1   male -11.33333
3 gene2 female -20.91111
4 gene2   male -11.33333
```

Comment: Okay, by changing the first line to `output <- sample %>%` I was able to save it. Wow that's blazing fast! I'll have to read more about that package, thanks very much!